# Why is shared volume 'Music' always missing from the DEVICES part of the sidebar in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, network, sidebar

I have a mid 2010 17" MacBook Pro (MBP).  I also have a Windows Home Server (WHS) that I connect to regularly from my MBP.  Normally when I connect to a share on the WHS, that mount point is listed in the sidebar of Finder under `DEVICES`.

## Problem

Under `DEVICES`, one share never shows:

> `Music`

All other WHS shares (`Photos`, `Movies`, `Documents` etc.) always show in that part of the sidebar when mounted.

The WHS (named `Bundywhs`) appears as expected under `SHARED`, I can take that route to connect to the `Music` volume.

I can eject the `Music` volume and reconnect, but it still doesn't show under `DEVICES`.

I upgraded from OS X 10.7.2 to 10.8, the problem persists.

It's not stopping me from doing anything, just more of a hassle not to have the quick shortcut.

### Questions

Is there a reason why `Music` will not show under `DEVICES`?

Is there anything I can do to make it show?

### Notes

Results of a command in Terminal:

```
defaults read com.apple.sidebarlists | grep Music
                Name = Music;
                Name = Music;
                Name = Music;
                Name = Music;
                Name = Music;
```

### Results of second command request

```
 };
            EntryType = 8;
            Icon = <496d6752 00000132 00000000 4642494c 00000126 00000002 00000000 00000000 01160003 00000000 c8c3bb37 0000482b 00000000 019faeb6 019fdd00 0000ca29 d33c0000 00000920 fffe0000 00000000 0000ffff ffff0001 0018019f aeb6019f acc8019f acc7019f a415019f a408019f a407000e 0036001a 00470065 006e0065 00720069 00630046 0069006c 00650053 00650072 00760065 00720049 0063006f 006e002e 00690063 006e0073 000f001a 000c004d 00610063 0069006e 0074006f 00730068 00200048 00440012 005a5379 7374656d 2f4c6962 72617279 2f436f72 65536572 76696365 732f436f 72655479 7065732e 62756e64 6c652f43 6f6e7465 6e74732f 5265736f 75726365 732f4765 6e657269 6346696c 65536572 76657249 636f6e2e 69636e73 00130001 2f00ffff 0000>;
            Name = Music;
        },

{
Alias = <00000000 009e0003 00010000 00000000 00004244 63750001 ffffffff ffffffff     00000000 00000000 00001201 fffe0000 00000000 0000ffff ffff000e 000c0005 004d0075 00730069     0063000f 000c0005 004d0075 00730069 00630012 00000013 000e2f56 6f6c756d 65732f4d 75736963     00090026 00266369 66730000 01000000 736d623a 2f2f5269 636b4062 756e6479 7768732f 4d757369 6300ffff 0000>;
EntryType = 8;
Name = Music;
}
{

"com.apple.LSSharedFileList.TemplateSystemSelector" = 1935822195;
};
Icon = <496d6752 0000001c 00000000 5359534c 00000010 00000000 744d7573>;
Name = Music;
},
{

                    {
            Alias = <00000000 009e0003 00010000 00000000 00004244 63750001 ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 00000000 00001201 fffe0000 00000000 0000ffff ffff000e 000c0005 004d0075 00730069 0063000f 000c0005 004d0075 00730069 00630012 00000013 000e2f56 6f6c756d 65732f4d 75736963 00090026 00266369 66730000 01000000 736d623a 2f2f5269 636b4062 756e6479 7768732f 4d757369 6300ffff 0000>;
            EntryType = 8;
            Name = Music;
            Visibility = AlwaysVisible;
            },
{
            Alias = <00000000 009e0003 00010000 00000000 00004244 63750001 ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 00000000 00001201 fffe0000 00000000 0000ffff ffff000e 000c0005 004d0075 00730069 0063000f 000c0005 004d0075 00730069 00630012 00000013 000e2f56 6f6c756d 65732f4d 75736963 00090026 00266369 66730000 01000000 736d623a 2f2f5269 636b4062 756e6479 7768732f 4d757369 6300ffff 0000>;
            EntryType = 8;
            Name = Music;
        },
                    {
```

Comment: You say that `Music` does appear under `DEVICES`. In which part of the sidebar does `Music` **not** appear? The `FAVORITES` part? In which part of the sidebar do `Photos`, `Movies` and `Documents` appear before you mount those volumes?

Comment: When looking at finder, there are three main groups on the left side.  Favorites, Shared, and Devices.  Anything volume from another computer is shown under devices when I mount them.  They do not appear anywhere before i mount them.  To access them I click on my whs (named Bundywhs) under shared.  That will list the volumes.  If I connect to a share then it will appear under Devices.  Except for music.

Answer (score 1):

When browsing the shared drive, you should be able to drag the shared folder to the side bar under favourites header.

- In reply to your comment. It could have just been accidentally trashed at some point without realising.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but it was bugging me why the one share wasn't showing.

Comment: It could have just been accidentally trashed at some point without realising.

Answer (score 0):

## First question

> Is there a reason why Music will not show?

One of the following commands, run in Terminal, might help towards an explanation.

```
defaults read com.apple.sidebarlists | grep Music
```

– expect a match of some sort. If no match, it'll be difficult to discover/guess how the entry was lost.

```
defaults read com.apple.sidebarlists favorites | grep -B 2 Visibility
```

Here, with Mountain Lion, I find `Visibility = NeverVisible` for some things – but not for the thing that I most recently removed from the sidebar, which leaves me wondering about `.plist` files that are used for preferred removals in Lion and Mountain Lion.

### Based on commentary, revisions and other answers

If using the File menu to add the volume to the sidebar does not allow the volume to appear under `DEVICES`, we might view this as a bug in the OS.

The following command should reveal detail of the five entries for `Music`:

```
defaults read com.apple.sidebarlists | grep -B 3 -A 2 Music
```

Comment: I am running Mountain Lion now.  When I run the first command, I get the following results:  Name = Music;
                Name = Music;
                Name = Music;
                Name = Music;
                Name = Music; visibilty is not neverVisible for anything I want.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that the upgrade to 10.8 has not worked around the problem with sidebar – true?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: OK, I added a little more to this answer. If you can edit your question to include (format as code) the result of the command, that'll be great.

Comment: I added those in.  One thing from the notes you made to this answer.  In my case I do not mount these volumes from the file menu.  They are mounted when I log my machine in via a script.

Comment: Thanks. Please mention the scripting, and whatever else may be relevant, in the question – it'll help people to read this page.

Answer (score 0):

## Second question

> Is there anything I can do to make it show?

If you want the `Music` *volume* to appear under `FAVORITES`:

- no (sorry).

It seems impossible to make an SMB a volume a favourite in the sidebar. You can drop the volume to that area of the sidebar, but the listing disappears immediately.

You can add the volume to the sidebar, after which it should appear (whenever mounted) under `DEVICES`.

With <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> in Finder, the volume can be a favourite in the **Connect to Server** dialogue. Example:

[image: screenshot of the Connect to Server dialogue, with 'Favorite Servers']

Anything other than the root of the volume can be a favourite in the sidebar of Finder.

There's an Apple-defined listing for `Music` but that's for the Music *folder* within the home directory. Example:

[image: screenshot of the Sidebar tab of Finder preferences]

Comment: As the question is becoming clearer, this answer is less relevant … but I'll leave it.

Answer (score 0):

My networked shares sometimes show, sometimes do not as well. If you manually `mount` them after finder is loaded, they should show.

Many users have reported problems with shares not showing in Finder sidebar, since Lion and Mountain Lion.

Answer (score -1):

You might try opening Finder preferences to see if the shared volume is being specifically excluded from the sidebar.

1. Make sure the Finder has focus (click on the Desktop or open a
   Finder window).
2. In the Finder menu (right of the apple menu), choose
   Preferences (or type command + ,).
3. Go to the Sidebar tab

Then look for the missing volume in the list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The individual shares are not listed there, just groups.  Bummer I was hoping this fixed it.

Comment: Well, shucks. I would next look into settings within your Windows Home Server environment — and now we're well outside of any expertise I have. Good luck!

Comment: The Sidebar tab of Finder preferences offers Apple-defined favourites, shared stuff, and classes of device; **not individual volumes**.